# How does Parse handle multiple pointers to the same PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

If I have a column of pointers in my Parse table, and I would like to download the `PFObjects` the pointers are pointing to, I know I would use the `.include` keyword. What I'm unsure about is how the downloading works. If I have many pointers pointing to the same `PFObject`, will the same thing happen when it downloads, i.e. that only one child `PFObject` will be downloaded and all the pointers will point to it or will the child `PFObject` be downloaded multiple times?

An example scenario:

- I am trying to find all posts with a certain hashtag. Each post has a pointer to the user that posted it. Some users posted multiple posts with the same hashtag, so there are multiple posts pointing to the same user. So, in this case, I would like to know whether or not this user will be downloaded for each post they posted under this hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

The child will be downloaded multiple times (I expect, you can check that if you scrape the traffic with a proxy). Wether the pointers all point to the same `PFObject` instance depends on if you are using local data (if you are they will, if you aren't they won't).

Comment: Could you post the link that you found this information? Or is it based on experience? I would like to do a bit more research into the topic.

Comment: I don't recall the page, if you read about the local data store it tells you about instance management.